# Copy content inside brackets and the word in front of bracket (i.e. a text object for function calls)

Tags: cut-copy-paste, custom-text-object

Quite often I copy or remove content inside brackets `d%` or `y%`.

```
MyAwesomeClass(
   ///content
)
```

But this way I get:

```
(
   ///content
)
```

Is there a way to copy word in front of the bracket too? So that the copied result is:

```
MyAwesomeClass(
   ///content
)
```

Comment: I thought up a non-plugin solution to your problem (added to the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Vim only solution

The simplest thing for the example you posted is probably to use visual
linewise mode - `va)V`will first select the content and the surrounding
parenthesis (but not the word in front) and the final `V` will switch to
linewise mode (thus additionally selecting everything before/after the
parentheses).

The above would not work in the more general case where you want to select the
inner function call (but *not* the outer one):

```
outer(inner(
   ///content
), some, more, args, here)
```

This case would need vim to have an understanding of what constitutes a
function call...

### Vim plugin solution (text objects)

I wrote the [vim-surround-funk](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-surround-funk)
plugin to do this kind of thing (and related things - see the end). In your case, the plugin gives you a new text
object `if` and `af` ('`i/a` function call'), so you could use either `vify` to
visually select and then yank it, or just `yif` to yank it directly:

Here are some visual selections of the text objects. Capitalising (i.e. `iF` and `aF`) extends the
characters considered as legal function name characters (e.g. the `.` in
python, but you can configure this). There is also the `in` and `an` text
objects (and their capital versions) that select the function call name. N.B.
In the below, the cursor can be in a variety of positions (but the cursor moves
after the selection, and I can't post the gif from the repo...):

[image]

#### But wait there's more!

The plugin was inspired by tpope's vim-surround plugin and allows you to delete, change and yank a surrounding function call along with its additional arguments. With the surrounding function call in the unnamed register, you can 'grip' any text object with it (including a different function call). 'Gripping' will wrap/encompass a word or function call with the one you have in the unnamed register.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in most cases: position your cursor on the content before the opening parentheses. That is, make sure the cursor is at the beginning of whatever you want to operate one.

Then `<operator>%` (*e.g.*, `d%`), just like you mentioned. Since `%` will jump to the closing parenthesis corresponding to the opening one ahead of the cursor, moving over the original content, you'll get the whole thing. That is, starting on `a` in `abc(def)`, `%` moves to `)` even though you didn't start on `(`. So similarly `d%` from that position deletes all of `abc(def)`.